# Django alterField does not preserve NOT NULL when modifying max_length

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm writing a django migration to change the max_length on CharField in the following model from 200 to 255, but doing so changes these fields from non-nullable to nullable. I want these fields to remain non-nullable.

With `sqlmigrate` I can see the sql that django runs for each migration:

#### Model definition

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models


class Account(models.Model):
    # Would be added by Django default anyways.
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_seen_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    project_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    notification_emails = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

#### Initial migration 0001

```
    BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE `pnmodels_account` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL, `last_seen_at` datetime NOT NULL, `project_token` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `notification_emails` longtext NOT NULL);

    COMMIT;
```

#### Migration 0002 to update max_length to 255

```
    BEGIN;
    ALTER TABLE `pnmodels_account` MODIFY `email` varchar(255);
    ALTER TABLE `pnmodels_account` MODIFY `name` varchar(255);
    ALTER TABLE `pnmodels_account` MODIFY `password` varchar(255);
    ALTER TABLE `pnmodels_account` MODIFY `project_token` varchar(255);
    ALTER TABLE `pnmodels_account` MODIFY `url` varchar(255);

    COMMIT;
```

I think the `MODIFY`s in 0002 need to include `NOT NULL`. Is this a django bug or am I missing something?

Using: Django==1.7.7, mysqlclient==1.3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24595

Waiting for the fix, you might need to do it 'by hand' or to make your column nullable and then not nullable

Comment: +1. I couldn't get the "make your column nullable and then not nullable" approach to work either. I assume you meant set blank=True on migration 0002 and blank=False on migration 0003 -- the generated sql still didn't include the NOT NULL.

Comment: The fix is included in django 1.8.1 and 1.7.8. The would be to migrate